# IIS - How to check if web site is working or not?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

Simply, I created an asp.net web site on IIS7

When I click on the "browse google.com on *:80(http)" it opens the real google.com not mine...
So that, I can not be sure my site is working properly or not.
(I dont want to make google1.com to see it is working)

I change the hosts file : 
xxx.yyy.zzz.kkk      google.com

now, when I browse the google.com it returns 404 not found
when I browse the xxx.yyy.zzz.kkk it returns 404 not found

I know that IIS working properly...
I know that Physical path is correct... So any idea why browsers returns 404 not found? Is it related with the physical file permission? I gived all permissions to SYSTEM and I clicked OK and then when I check again it was returned pervious state... I didnt work..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Your question is unclear.  If you want to go to Google, why not just `<a href="https://www.google.com/">click here to go to Google</a>`?

Comment: When you ping google.com. Is the IP of the response the IP of your IIS?

Comment: No I dont want to go to google.  Actually, I'm trying to move a web site from one web server to another web server. A named server runs my web site. also, I uploaded  uploaded web site to B named server when I try to browse on B named web server It opens the web site that located on A named server but I want to check my site is working on B named server or not...

Comment: @Sandro, yes IP adres is my ISS's IP adress not google.com's IP adress..

Comment: Clarify what you are trying to do. This may have more to do with DNS (re: moving site), than anything related to IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that anonymous authentication is enabled for your IIS application and you don't have any special configurations enabled, it's probably an authorization problem.

Make sure you grant the necessary permissions for the group `IIS_IUSRS` and/or the user `IUSR` for the physical folder of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with aspnet registration to IIS. Running this with admin rights might help to solve the problem:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework..\v.....\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Please replace ..'s with appropriate values.